# Angular 6 Form not passing variable to URL

Tags: javascript, python, html, angular

I am trying to create a form in angular that takes a name, passes it to a URL, and returns a portion of a .json file. I can't figure out why the url is not getting updated though.

The HTML:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="processForm($engineer)">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="engineerselectform">Engineer Name</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="engineerselectform" name="engineer" [(ngModel)]="engineer">
            <option></option>
            <option>Smith</option>
            <option>Jones</option>
            <option>Clark</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit"  aria-pressed="true">
</form>
```

The Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ScheduleService } from '../schedule.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-schedule',
  templateUrl: './schedule.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./schedule.component.scss']
})
export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit {
  engineer;

  constructor(
    private scheduleService: ScheduleService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {}
    processForm(engineer: string) {
      this.route.params.subscribe(params=> { const engineer = params["engineer"];
      this.scheduleService.getschedule(engineer).subscribe(engineer => this.engineer = engineer);
    });
  }
}
```

The Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ScheduleService {
  apiUrl ='http://127.0.0.1:5000/schedule'
  engineer;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getschedule(engineer: string){
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}?engineer=${this.engineer}`);
  }
}
```

The Flask API backend:

```
@app.route('/schedule', methods = ['GET'])
def engineer_location_api():
    if "engineer" in request.args:
        print ('did this')
        engineer_name = request.args["engineer"]
        print ("engineer name:", engineer_name)
    else:
        return "not found, sorry"

    answer = {}
    with open(LOC1, "r") as file:
        check_loc1 = json.load(file)
        for item in check_loc1["LOC1"]:
            if engineer_name in item["Engineer"]:
                answer.update(item)
            else:
                continue
    with open(LOC2, "r") as file:
        check_loc2 = json.load(file)
        for item in check_loc2:
            if engineer_name in item:
                answer.update(item)
            else:
                continue

    if answer:
        return answer
    else:

        return 'engineer not found'

app.run()
```

the error:

```
ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/schedule?engineer=undefined", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure during parsing for http://127.0.0.1:5000/schedule?engineer=undefined", error: {…} }
core.js:6014:19
```

As I understand it, when I hit submit the process form function should send the engineer variable to the component where it sets it as a parameter that it provides to the service which should fill out the URL. But regardless of how I play around with it, the engineer always comes back as undefined. Clearly I'm missing something core to passing the variable.

Also, I'm super new and therefore there are probably other things in this code that are ugly or not best practice, feel free to rip into it, I figure my understanding can only go up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to subscribe to activated url if your data is coming from form. You have to remove the $event from processForm because we will add the global variable in your service function. Please have a look on below example

```
<form (ngSubmit)="processForm()">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="engineerselectform">Engineer Name</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="engineerselectform" name="engineer" [(ngModel)]="engineer">
            <option></option>
            <option value="smith">Smith</option>
            <option value="jones">Jones</option>
            <option value="clark">Clark</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit"  aria-pressed="true">
</form>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ScheduleService } from '../schedule.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-schedule',
  templateUrl: './schedule.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./schedule.component.scss']
})
export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit {
  engineer;
  receivedEngineers;
  constructor(
    private scheduleService: ScheduleService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {}
    processForm() {
      this.scheduleService.getschedule(this.engineer).subscribe(engineer => this.receivedEngineers = engineer);
    });
  }
}
```

```
 getschedule(engineer: string){
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}?engineer=${engineer}`);
  }
```

The engineer is now accessed from parameter of getSchedule() function.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I made the changes you submitted, specifically to processForm() and the form tag itself and am getting the same error code.

I'm unsure if it's worth noting but on the line:
```private route: ActivatedRoute```
i'm getting a message that: "property 'route' is declared but its value is never read ts(6138)"

Comment: Hi i have just edited the HTML part of my answer. It was very silly mistake from my side. I was not giving value in options. The updated code is `<option value="smith">Smith</option>`

Comment: Added values in my HTML, same error. I re-compiled the code just to make sure there wasn't anything cached that was causing a problem. Another point to note is that in the **schedule.service.ts** file in ```getschedule(engineer: string)```, engineer also has the note that it is declared but never read, however if I remove it then it causes an error in **schedule.component.ts**.

Does there need to be another declaration in the constructor in schedule.service?

Comment: Yes yes yes, You are right engineer was never read in getSchedule() method. Try changing this.engineer to engineer from your getSchedule function. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much.

Comment: Awesome. I would appreciate if you upvote the answer :)

Comment: I did, but I think since I have less than 15 reputation it doesn't display.